# Getting a list of friends and then displaying a friends list

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm struggling with how I can get the data of a user's friends from Firebase's Realtime Database to build it out in Flutter. The structure of the database looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X09XI.jpg)

Essentially, in my code, I'm listening to changes in an user's friends list from the database and then getting the friend ID so that I can query the rest of the friend's metadata (image, name, etc.) to build out the friend's list in the app. The issue I'm running into is that I can't seem to get the Json data to map correct and I get the following error:

Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Any insight would be appreciated

```
class _FriendsScreenState extends State<FriendsScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    getUserFriendsList();
    super.initState();
  }

  getUserFriendsList() async {
    rtdb.child('friends').child(widget.currentUserID).onValue.listen((event) {
      final data = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value);

      data.keys.forEach((element) async {
        DataSnapshot userInfo = await usersRef.child(element).get();
        User users = User.fromJson(json.decode(userInfo.value));
       
      });
    });
  }

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return User(
      imageUrl: parsedJson['userImageUrl'],
      userFirstName: parsedJson['userFirstName'],
      userLastName: parsedJson['userLastName'],
      userID: parsedJson['userID'],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem in:

```
User users = User.fromJson(json.decode(userInfo.value));
```

why u have used JSON decode (json.decode & User.fromJson) twice?
However, for further analysis, you should provide data and log it.

Comment: User.fromJson is user defined and it's purpose is to provide value to the objects of user class. It is not decoding the json.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to decode the json as [DataSnaphot.value](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot/value.html) "returns the contents of [the] data snapshot as native types."

So `userInfo.value` does not return a `String`, it returns a `Map` instead.

**Solution:**

Convert the result to a `Map<String, dynamic>` from the `_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>` type it returns.

Change this line:

```
User users = User.fromJson(json.decode(userInfo.value));
```

to this:

```dart
User users = User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>.from(userInfo.value));
```

Comment: Thanks Victor! This was the issue